# Deserializing struct from Kafka avro format with from_avro function in Spark does not work correctly

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming

I used `to_avro` to serialize a struct field in dataframe into 'value' and write to a kafka topic.
My struct has several string fields. I tested and all field has value.
Using Spark Streaming, I read the topic and use `from_avro` to deserialize the value with the exact schema that was used to serialize the struct.

```
select(from_avro($"value", schema).as("value"))
```

The return is a struct field in result dataframe. However, always there're some field in the struct without value. Just some of the fields have correct value.
Can this be a bug in `to_avro`/`from_avro` functions or I did not use them correctly?

Comment: Did you get to solve the issue? I'm running into exactly the same problem. if you could share your solution that would be helpful for me.